# How do I split an address in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to split an address to three parts using python.
Given the following adresses:

```
103 Rur de Rennes 75006 Paris
57-59 avenue du Président Wilson 93210 Saint Denis la Plaine
```

I need to split into three parts(address, code, location), so the final result should be:

```
103 Rur de Rennes,  75006,  Paris
57-59 avenue du Président Wilson,  93210,  Saint Denis la Plaine
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Is there any pattern in the address you can assume?

Comment: Using regex is a good way to go here. But it isn't too beginner friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.split` will get you most of the way, if we can assume the code is a 5-digit number.

```
>>> re.split("(\d{5})", "103 Rur de Rennes 75006 Paris")
['103 Rur de Rennes ', '75006', ' Paris']
```

To trim the whitespace, you can just use the `strip` method:

```
>>> [x.strip() for x in re.split("(\d{5})", "103 Rur de Rennes 75006 Paris")]
['103 Rur de Rennes', '75006', 'Paris']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the address starts with the street number and the next number will be the code, you can [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the address and look for a number from the right:

```py
def sep_address(address):
    parts = address.split()
    for i in range(len(parts)-1, 0, -1):
        if parts[i].isdigit():
            return ' '.join(parts[:i]), parts[i], ' '.join(parts[i+1:])

print(sep_address("103 Rur de Rennes 75006 Paris"))
print(sep_address("57-59 avenue du Président Wilson 93210 Saint Denis la Plaine"))
```

Gives:

```
('103 Rur de Rennes', '75006', 'Paris')
('57-59 avenue du Président Wilson', '93210', 'Saint Denis la Plaine')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def three_parts(addr):
    splitter = re.compile(r"^(?P<ADDRESS>\d+-?\d*[\w\s]+[^\d])(?P<CODE>\d+)\s+(?P<LOCATION>[\w\s]+)")
    retval = splitter.match(addr)
    if retval:
        # if you prefer a dictionary use retval.groupdict()
        return [retval.group("ADDRESS"), retval.group("CODE"), retval.group("LOCATION")]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    addresses = [
        "103 Rur de Rennes 75006 Paris",
        "57-59 avenue du Président Wilson 93210 Saint Denis la Plaine",
        "bogus address"
    ]    
    for addr in addresses:
        print(addr)
        parts = three_parts(addr)
        print(parts)
        print("-"*40)
```

Output

```
103 Rur de Rennes 75006 Paris
['103 Rur de Rennes ', '75006', 'Paris']
----------------------------------------
57-59 avenue du Président Wilson 93210 Saint Denis la Plaine
['57-59 avenue du Président Wilson ', '93210', 'Saint Denis la Plaine']
----------------------------------------
bogus address
None
----------------------------------------
```